# PHP PDO returns false count of columns

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So what I'm trying to do, is that I want to return the number of columns in a where clause. Currently this is working:

```
$total = $pdo->query('
    SELECT
         COUNT(*)
    FROM
         _TABLENAME_
')->fetchColumn();

echo $total .' Rows Found';
// Outputs 10 if, 10 rows are found.
```

But when I try to do it with a `WHERE LIKE` cause, it won't work.

```
$gr = '%'.$_GET['genres'].'%';
$total = $pdo->query('
    SELECT
         COUNT(*)
    FROM
         _TABLENAME_
    WHERE
         genres
    LIKE
         '.$gr.'
')->fetchColumn();

echo $total . ' Rows Found';
// Outputs 1, even if more are found
```

But obviously that won't work, when that's not how you make a PDO Execute statement, so I tried to do this:

```
$gr = '%'.$_GET['genres'].'%';
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `_TABLENAME_` WHERE genres LIKE :gr ';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':gr', $gr, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$total = $stmt->rowCount();

echo $total . ' Rows Found';
```

But yet again the result is only 1.

Comment: What does your database data look like?

Comment: SELECT COUNT will only return a single row, with a single "column" entry containing the count value; you need to get that column value returned, not the rowcount

Comment: @showdev genres like: Action / Adventure / Comedy

Comment: @PhiterFernandes what do you mean, by my code is ugly? It's total standard, so wtf

Comment: @MarkBaker oh thanks, I got an idea what you mean.

Comment: @markBaker got it fixed by adding a `if($row = fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       $total = $stmt->rowCount($row['id']);
      }`

Answer (score 1):

As PHP manual says :

> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the
>   number of rows affected by a SELECT statement.

Instead

> use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same
>   predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use
>   PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will
>   be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.

Check out it here : [Counting rows returned by a SELECT statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).
In the PHP manual you can learn much more use cases :)

I hope this help you to understand the behavior.